# Run SQL commands inside postgres docker container using docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql

I can run SQL commands inside a [postgres](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres) docker container using `psql`:

```
psql -U postgres -c "SELECT * FROM USERS;"
```

Now, I want to run this command using docker-compose. Here's what I have so far but no luck:

```
docker-compose run db psql -U postgres -c "SELECT * FROM USERS;"
# psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
#     Is the server running locally and accepting
#     connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can't. See postgresql [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/Dockerfile#L220):

> CMD ["postgres"]

The final `CMD` is `postgres` which will start the postgresql server.

If you use `docker-compose run db psql -U postgres -c "SELECT * FROM USERS;"`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/):

> the command passed by run overrides the command defined in the service configuration.
>  For example, if the web service configuration is started with bash, then
>
> ```
> docker-compose run web python app.py overrides it with python app.py.
> ```

So, the original `postgres` command never have chance to run, which means the `postgresql server` not start, then you have your error to connect to server.

I don't know if next alternative meet your requirement, just FYI:

First, use `docker-compose up -d db` to start the service.

Second, use `docker-compose exec db psql -U postgres -c "select * from pg_user;"` for example to run your command.